# Javascript progress bar not showing correct percentage of completion

Tags: javascript

In the following code I am trying to make the progress bar show 100% but it stays at 66%. It is a quiz with three questions. It works just fine when on first and second question showing 33% and 66% respectively after submitting the third question it still shows 66% but the bar fully completes spanning the entire width of the bar. Complete codepen [here.](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/ExKGOWj). How do I show 100% after third question? Thank you.

Progress bar JS code:

```
function move(i) {
    console.log('i: ' + i);
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    switch(i) {
      case 0:
        elem.style.width = "33%";
        elem.innerHTML = "33%";
        break;
      case 1:
        elem.style.width = "66%";
        elem.innerHTML = "66%";
        break;
      case 2:
        elem.style.width = "100%";
        elem.innerHTMl = "100%";
    }
  }
```

Comment: `innerHTML` in case 2  not `innerHTMl` - the rest of your code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You must try this

```
<style>
#myProgress {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
#myBar {
    width: 1%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    text-align:center;color:white;
}
</style>
<p id="count">1%</p>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<button onclick="move(10)">10%</button> 
<button onclick="move(33)">33%</button> 
<button onclick="move(66)">66%</button> 
<button onclick="move(100)">100%</button> 

<script>
function move(x) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var count = document.getElementById("count");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= x) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
            count.innerHTML = width + '%';
        }
    }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Any specific reason of `You must try this` ? whats changed and better then OP existing code which work perfectly ?

Comment: I'm sure this is the "correct" and "complete" code. I'm thinking not only about this particular case,I hope this helping other users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have a more generalized approach to do this, Since myQuestions variable can have any length then using switch case wouldn't be sutiable to do this.

```js
function move(slide, total) {
  console.log('slide: ' + slide);
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  const percent = (slide + 1) / total * 100;
  elem.style.width = `${percent}%`;
  elem.innerHTML = percent != 100 ? `${percent.toPrecision(2)}` : "100%";
}

// From your code you can just call like this
move(currentSlide, myQuestions.length);
```

Hope you find this helpful.